# Order by no funciona - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo esta tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hago esta consulta para obtener datos ordenados y crear un `select`:

```
select id, nombre from usuarios_grupos ORDER BY `nombre` ASC
```

... y este es el resultado, sorpresivamente **no lo ordena**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Antes funcionaba ¿Qué he cambiado?

Pues he pasado de un servidor dedicado *Windows* a otro con *Linux* y *Apache*.

Añado 12/1/17:

Lo curioso es que sí aplica un tipo de orden, es decir, esta consulta:

**select id, nombre from usuarios_grupos ORDER BY nombre ASC**

Devuelve:
Id  nombre Ascendente 1
10  Módulo pago
4   Supervisor
9   Tienda
2   Administrador
1   Creador
8   Socio
3   Usuario

Y esta consulta:

**select id, nombre from usuarios_grupos ORDER BY nombre DESC**

Devuelve:
 id     nombre Descendente 1
3   Usuario
8   Socio
1   Creador
2   Administrador
9   Tienda
4   Supervisor
10  Módulo pago

Este es el código php que se ejecuta, con el mismo resultado:

```
<select name="id_grupo" size="1" <?=$noacceso?>>
<?php
$sql = "select id, nombre from usuarios_grupos";
if((int)$_SESSION["grupo"] !== 1) $sql .= " where id<>1" ;
$sql .= " order by nombre";

$result = $conn->query($sql) Or Die ("ER0081: Error cargando datos");

while($rs = $result->fetch_object())
{
    If ((int)$rs->id !== $id_grupo)
    {
        Echo "<option value='" . $rs->id . "'>" . $rs->nombre . "</option>";
    }
    Else
    {
        Echo "<option selected value='" . $rs->id . "'>" . $rs->nombre . "</option>";
    }
}
$result->close();
?>
```

Comment: ¿Has probado otras consultas para ver si algo funciona? Por ejemplo, cambiar el `ASC` por `DESC`, ordenar por `id`, etc.. Solo para entender por donde va la falla.

Comment: ¿Estas seguro de que los registros en la columna `Nombre` no tienen caracteres "especiales" (no visibles)?

Comment: Estamos viendo directamente el resultado que entrega la base de datos?, o lo que obtienes ya publicado en tu aplicación?

Comment: has probado de quitarle las comillas a "nombre" en donde pones el ORDER BY

Comment: Todas estas pruebas ya las realicé. El código funcionaba bien en servidor Windows, ahora en apache no.

Comment: POR FAVOR, mirad la modificación de hoy, sí se produce un orden, pero no sé por qué criterio.

Comment: Hola @Manu, que raro tu problema. Lo siento. ¿Has probado ordenar por el `id`, solo para ver si por lo menos con esa ordena como se espera, o si también actúa de forma completamente rara. Dependiendo del resultado, tal vez tenga alguna idea de otras pruebas que puedan ayudar a diagnosticar el problema.

Comment: INCREIBLE: Si ordeno por cualquier otro campo lo hace correctamente. He cambiado el cotejamiento varias veces y nada.

Comment: @Manu: ¿Puedes por favor agregar a tu pregunta el resultado de la consulta siguiente? `select id, nombre, ascii(nombre) from usuarios_grupos order by nombre`. Como comentó @Marcos ayer, tal vez tengas caracteres especiales escondidos en el campo `nombre`, y esta consulta ayudará a determinar si ese es el problema.

Comment: Hola, mira esto es lo que devuelve:

 id  nombre Ascendente 1  ascii(nombre)    
10  Módulo pago  32  
4  Supervisor  32  
9  Tienda  32  
2  Administrador  65  
1  Creador  67  
8  Socio  83  
3  Usuario  85

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te pedí correr la consulta siguiente para diagnosticar el problema:

```sql
select id, nombre, ascii(nombre)
  from usuarios_grupos
 order by nombre
```

Y tu resultado fue:

```
id  nombre        ascii(nombre) 
--  ------        -------------
10  Módulo pago   32 
4   Supervisor    32 
9   Tienda        32 
2   Administrador 65 
1   Creador       67 
8   Socio         83 
3   Usuario       85
```

Con ese resultado se puede ver más claramente cuál es el problema. Como puedes ver, el código ASCII del primer carácter de los primeros 3 registros es `32`, o sea, un espacio (`' '`).

De modo que para esos 3 registros, aunque no se vea claramente a primera vista, los nombres tienen los valores siguientes (nota el espacio en frente):

- `' Módulo pago'`
- `' Supervisor'`
- `' Tienda'`

Y como el carácter `32` se considera inferior a los caracteres alfanuméricos, eso explica por qué esos 3 registros aparecen primero.

Obviamente, te tocará decidir cómo arreglar el problemita. Tal vez quieras corregir los datos para remover los espacios en exceso:

```sql
update usuarios_grupos
   set nombre = trim(nombre);
```

O tal vez te conformes con arreglar el `ORDER BY` para que ignore los espacios de más:

```sql
select id, nombre
  from usuarios_grupos
 order by trim(nombre)
```

Answer (score -1):

Hola creo que el problema viene del tipo de cotejamiento ya que la columna `Nombre` la tienes como **utf8_general_ci**.

Precisión para ordenar los datos:

**utf8_unicode_ci:** Se basa en el estándar Unicode para ordenar, y ordena con precisión en una amplia gama de idiomas.

**utf8_general_ci:** Se acerca mucho para ordenar correctamente con Unicode en muchos idiomas comunes, pero tiene una serie de imprecisiones al ordenar en algunos idiomas, por lo que no es recomendable para la correcta ordenación en todos los idiomas.

Prueba cambiando el tipo de cotejamiento y nos cuentas

Comment: Hola es 1ra vez que respondo al menos podrían decirme porque el voto negativo para saber si dije o seguí algún procedimiento mal?

Comment: Hola El Cóndor. Lo siento por lo del voto negativo. Pero la realidad es que lo que dices no es posible. No importa si se trata de un collate general o unicode, ninguno de estos tendría dificultad en ordenar caracteres básicos como `A`, `C`, `M`, `S`, etc... Si se trata de caracteres especiales, tal vez, pero no es el caso aquí.

Comment: Ah bien soy nuevo en esto y solo quería ayudar, creo que me precipite en responder

Comment: No hay problema. Aquí dejo un enlace que demuestra que ambos collate pueden ordenar estos valores correctamente: http://rextester.com/RAC68089, por lo que el problema debe ser otro.

Comment: He probado con los dos y nada, fue lo primero que cambié.

Answer (score -1):

Has probado con poner el número de columna en el order by, es decir ORDER BY 2 para ordenar por la segunda columna?

```
select id, nombre from usuarios_grupos ORDER BY 2 ASC
```

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar por qué eso solucionaría el problema?

Comment: Obtengo el mismo resultado.

Answer (score -2):

quita las comillas que tienes en `nombre` y te funcionará.

El **`order by`** quedaría así:

```
 order by nombre;
```

Saludos!

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar por qué eso solucionaría el problema?

Comment: Que va, ya probé, hace los mismo.

Answer (score -2):

intenta con

```
select ug.id, ug.nombre from usuarios_grupos ug ORDER BY ug.nombre ASC
```

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar por qué eso solucionaría el problema?

Comment: Nada, hace los mismo.